# How to Keep Textures High-Res Without Scaling UVs Ridiculously

Tags: texturing

I have a recurring issue where my textures, although seemingly high enough quality, appear very grainy and low-res when applied to a model. However, I've found that scaling the UVs up excessively makes the texture appear way higher fidelity on the model, but I'm pretty confident this is a terrible way of doing this. Am I missing something obvious? For context, I have my Unit Scale on .01 (for exporting to UE4) and the barrel is currently a very large barrel coming in at about 2x2x3m, if that changes anything.

[image: Pic 1: UVs scaled up large]

[image: Pic 2: Result of large UVs, much higher quality texture]

For comparison, it looks pretty bad to me when the UVs are scaled "appropriately":

[image: Pic 3: UVs scaled "appropriately" within the bounds]

[image: Pic 4: Awful low-res result of normal UV scale]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll note that by default, textures loop endlessly. Given that, despite the fact that your UVs are "off the texture", the texture is still being applied with the same coverage, just at a different scale.

To fix your issue, you may want to employ a Mapping node.

### Setup

Let's start with the node setup;

[image]

Note: for the "Type", I've selected "Texture", since I want to apply scaling at a factor relative to the image dimensions.

### Examples

The default value for scaling on the mapping node;

[image]

Higher value;

[image]

Lower Value;

[image]

As you can see, no modification of the UV is necessary. Technically, it's exactly the same result, but the effect is applied via a different method.

### Alternate method without nodes

Open up your favorite image editor. Load the texture;

[image]

Expand the canvas size by 200% (or more, depending on the desired resolution);

[image]

Copy the image into the empty space;

[image]

Save, use as texture, enjoy increased resolution at the cost of disk and memory, but not having the mess with equivalent nodes in two programs.

### Scaling two textures differently with the same UV

Ok, starting with the following node setup;

[image]

I've painted some wood onto this burlap cube using the MixRGB node, and a black and white image as the factor (black indicates 0, white indicates 1, grays in the middle indicate a mix);

[image]

Now I can edit the mapping of each texture separately. Here we have enlarged wood, and reduced burlap;

[image]

And now, the opposite;

[image]

I do not know if there is an equivalent node setup in UE4 One might suggest considering baking these textures, and exporting this object with it's own set of textures. Of course, that means more textures, and memory, and etc (and I think you wanted to do this programmatically, not just throw more textures at it).

### Blender file for examination

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So to mimic this for an exported FBX in Unreal I should just re-create that node in a UE4 engine?

Comment: Yes, you would have to scale the image in Unreal the same way, otherwise the texture will render differently between Blender and UE4.

Comment: Gotcha. Just did it in UE4 and it worked great, but if I have multiple different textures within one material (e.g. wood for a barrel along with metal for the rings around it) it obviously throws off the placement of the UVs and things no longer line up properly. Any way around this other than just using two different materials? Trying to reduce draw calls. Thanks again

Comment: First thing's first; Your original post mentioned that to get the desired resolution, you tried scaling the UVs way up. Did you fix all the UVs so that they naturally line up (and I presume, some of them looked low res)?

Comment: https://imgur.com/PY0UuYI

https://imgur.com/zVLZtKX

This is with the UVs all lined up properly. At scale 1, everything displays normally. The picture with the messed up texture is at scale 3, set in the UE node. I know this is getting a bit out of the scope of Blender assistance but I appreciate the help haha.

Comment: Haha, no problem. I'm sure we could figure a technical way out of this, but the easiest way? Take the image, copy it into a larger texture;

Comment: Well, I'm already at around 2k-3k on the size so I'm actually trying to reduce it...Hmm. Am I just running into a dead end trying to keep the image the same size or smaller while scaling up UVs that are specific to certain parts of the texture? I feel like that's getting paradoxical lol. If nothing else I could bite the bullet and accept the extra draw calls but that becomes intense when I've got trees that only have one material slot that would end up being 3-4 more material slots if I did each texture separately.

Comment: I see. Yes, then the addition to my answer won't do :p . I can't see your node setup in UE4, because that image is microscopic, but if there's a way to scale just that one texture, not the entire shader, then that would be what you want. Alternatively, if you could assign one UV to a texture, and another UV to another texture, that would work.

Comment: Yeah sorry, took that photo with my phone 'cuz that's on the other PC. Guess it's not as visible as I thought haha. It's just a TextureCoordinate node with U and V both set to 3. So hopefully last question: Where/how would I go about assigning individual UVs to different textures? That sounds perfect! I tried in the static mesh but it only showed me the UVs, couldn't see a way to edit them there.

Comment: I mean, I can show you how in Blender :p I don't know UE4. Stand by, updating answer...

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I've also attached the .blend file for you

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll look over this and see if I can port it into UE4. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I hope it works :) If it does, don't forget to mark an answer as the accepted one. Otherwise, feel free to come back and request clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly connecting the *UV Vector* output from the **UV Map** node to the image input in the material nodes, insert a *Vector > Mapping* node. You can use it's scale component to scale the existing UVs, or move/rotate them.

For scaling only a *Vector Math* node set to multiply will do just as well.

[image: mapping node demo]

<sup>This will obviously not work in an exported object for another program without corresponding material nodes.</sup>

Comment: Cool, thank you! So I should just re-create this setup in UE4 in a material, correct?

Answer (score 0):

There's no issues at all (that I've ever encountered at least) with scaling up your UVs. This is a common way to deal with tileable textures. Another way is to scale the texture in the material settings, but this does the exact same thing, just behind the scenes, and probably won't export as nicely.

One thing to consider is you also don't want higher texture resolution than you need, as it could impact performance or memory usage. It's very common in games to be able to see the textures get a bit grainy when up very close, so just keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you, very practical answer. Is 1024x1024 a reasonable average for most textures, and maybe higher (2 or 3k?) for high-res stuff such as player and weapon meshes?

Comment: There's no one size fits all method for texture size that I know of. Generally you start with figuring about how detailed you object needs to be and go from there. You can also use some techniques to reduce the texture size needed, like stacking your UVs on top of each other.